# Variable scope, or selector issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

can anyone help explain to me why `maxWidth` is still equal to -1 after running through this code? https://jsfiddle.net/nfy7xboL/ Note: when I just us a selector of `$("menu-item")` the code works as expected

I don't know if I am having trouble with javascript variables or what, but I figure if I set `var menuItem = $("menu-item");` and replace the selector within the `.load()` function, it would have the same output as just running `$("menu-item").each(...`

EDIT: Full scriptfile + HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/nfy7xboL/7/

HTML

```
<div class="menu-primary-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-11" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-11" style="width: 282px;"><a href="http://192.168.33.10/">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-9 current_page_item menu-item-13" style="width: 282px;"><a href="http://192.168.33.10/hourslocation/">Hours/Location</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14" style="width: 282px;"><a href="http://192.168.33.10/menu/">Menu</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-52" style="width: 282px;"><a href="http://192.168.33.10/mooooooooooreeeee/">MOOOOOOOOOOREEEEE</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-57" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-57" style="width: 282px;"><a href="http://192.168.33.10/more-stuff/">more stuff</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-58" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58" style="width: 282px;"><a href="http://192.168.33.10/even/">even</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
var menuItem = $("menu-item");
var menuContainer = $(".menu-primary-menu-container");
var maxWidth = -1;

$(window).load(function () {
    //declare variables
    var resizeTimer;

    var count = $(".menu-item").length;
    console.log(menuItem);
    // Loop menu items, and retrieve greatest width, to be multiplied by count
    console.log(menuItem);
    menuItem.each(function () {
        maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, $(this).width());
        console.log(maxWidth);
    });
    console.log(maxWidth);
    // Only resize li elements if screen width is greater than menu width
    if ($(window).width() > maxWidth * count) {
        resize_menu();
    } else {
        // or else show the mobile menu
        mobile_menu();
    };
    // On a resize (delayed for performance)
    $(window).on('resize', function (e) {
        console.log(maxWidth);
        //clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        //resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        // again, if window is less than menu, show mobile 
        if ($(window).width() < maxWidth * count) {
            mobile_menu();
        } else {
            // or else, show regular menu
            // Note: resize, incase screen was loaded smaller than menu

            $("#menu-primary-menu").removeAttr('style');
            $("#menu-primary-menu").removeAttr('width');
            $(".menu-primary-menu-container ul li").css("display", "inline-block");
            $(".menu-primary-menu-container ul li a").css("min-height", "70px");
            $(".menu-primary-menu-container ul li").css("width", maxWidth);
            show_menu();
        };
        //}, 50);
    });

    // if the mobile menu icon is clicked, show menu
    $("#mobile-menu").click(function () {
        $("#menu-primary-menu").css("max-width", "960px");
        $("#menu-primary-menu").css("margin", "0 auto");
        $(".menu-primary-menu-container ul li").css("width", "100%");
        $(".menu-primary-menu-container ul li").css("display", "block");
        $(".menu-primary-menu-container ul li a").css("min-height", "40px");
        show_menu();
    });
});

function resize_menu() {

    var maxWidth = -1;

    $(".menu-item").each(function () {
        maxWidth = maxWidth > $(this).width() ? maxWidth : $(this).width();
    });

    $(".menu-item").each(function () {
        $(this).width(maxWidth);
    });
}

function mobile_menu() {
    $(".menu-primary-menu-container").css("display", "none");
    $("#mobile-menu").css("display", "block");
}

function show_menu() {
    $("#mobile-menu").css("display", "none");
    $(".menu-primary-menu-container").css("display", "initial");
}
```

Comment: **Missed `.`-class selector in `$("menu-item")`**. No need of `load` event, use `ready`. See [MCVE]

Comment: $("menu-item") it is a selector, not an attribute, you need to modify it and it will look like this $('.menu-item') or $('#menu-item')

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to display the relevant code directly. You should do that anyway in a general sense, but in this case your fiddle is non-functional given it has no html. Anyway, the problem is that if you try to select the elements before the DOM has loaded then there are not yet any elements to select.

Comment: You should have this at the 1st line: var menuItem = $(".menu-item"); See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nfy7xboL/13/

Comment: Including the dot and selecting the elements only after load: https://jsfiddle.net/nfy7xboL/15/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item">Text</li>
    <li class="menu-item">More Text</li>
    <li class="menu-item">The longest Text</li>
</ul>
```

Secondly the CSS code:

```
li { display: inline-block; }
```

And finally the JS script:

```
menuItem = $(".menu-item");
var maxWidth = -1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    menuItem.each(function() {
        maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, $(this).width());
    });

    alert('max width: ' + maxWidth);
});
```

Also here is a jsfiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/nfy7xboL/17/

Comment: When I use `.ready()` instead of `.load()` I get a smaller value for `maxWidth()`

Comment: Then use `$(window).load();` but this is the method which is working. On jsfiddle which i have posted you can see that it is the same amount - the max width of the list item and the value returned from `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `menu-item` is the class name for your `li` elements, you should be selecting them using the class selector:

```
var menuItem = $(".menu-item");
```

See the modified code here https://jsfiddle.net/nfy7xboL/13/ which prints a `maxWidth` of 282.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have defined a HTML tag `<menu-item>`, then `$("menu-item")` is not going to work you wanted. See jQuery's documentation on [Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to understand how to use them to retrieve the elements you want.

Since you have `<li class="menu-item"></li>`, you want to use `$(".menu-item")`:

> Class Selector (".class")
>   Selects all elements with the given class.